# Does Artifactory Plugin need to be installed on each TFS Build machine

Tags: tfs

I recently installed the Artifactoy plugin on my desktop and configured one of my solutions to use it. I checked in the project with the new files and folderes that the plugin created.

I tried to build the project locally on my desktop and it was successful. When I tried to Queue a build in TFS for the same project it failed with the following errors:

> .artifactory\Deploy.targets (26, 5) The
>   "JFrog.Artifactory.ArtifactoryBuild" task could not be loaded from the
>   assembly
>   C:\Agent_work\2\s\packages\Artifactory.2.3.1\lib\net45\JFrog.Artifactory.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Agent_work\2\s\packages\Artifactory.2.3.1\lib\net45\JFrog.Artifactory.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. Process
>   'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

Then there were 4 warnings, I'm not sure they are the problem.

Do I have to install the Artifactory Plugin on each Build machine?

Comment: It looks like you need to run a NuGet package restore as part of your build.

Comment: Which kind of build are you using? Vnext or XAML bulid?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the build runs without any error or warning, you must make sure the build environment on your build machine be the same as your local develop machine.

Either install *Artifactory Plugin*  on the build machine or use **nuget package restore** in your build definition.  Details please refer this tutorial:  [MSBuild Artifactory Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/MSBuild+Artifactory+Plugin)

> **Package Restore with Team Foundation Build**
>
> For Team Foundation Build 2013 on-premises, the default Build Process
> Templates already implement the NuGet Package Restore Workflow without
> any special configuration. To avoid NuGet Package Restore from outside
> the plugin, you need to remove it from the workflow.

If you are using XAML in TFS2013, please double check the configuration, if you are using vNext in TFS2015 and above, please manually add it.

Comment: We are using TFS 2015 update 3. It is not the XAML build. I will look at the link above and test it out.

Comment: Hi @PatDelaney Have you figured out this issue? You could add related nuget package restore task in your vNext build definition.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure what you are asking me to do. I'm new to some of this.